# What are the implications of invalid geometries

Tags: postgis, geometry, invalid-data

I've imported some data in a Postgis database and some of the geometries are reported invalid (ST_IsValidReason reports self-intersection or ring self-intersection).

The queries I am performing don't seem affected by the invalid aspect of these geometries (i'm only using ST_Distance queries).

What are the things that break when geometries are invalid?

Is fixing these geometries "automatically" (buffer(geom, 0) or ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(geom, 0.0001)) an option?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Keeping malformed data is a bad idea, because you can never predict when and where will the failure occur.** Moreover, malformed data can cause [Heisenbugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug), the most vicious and illusive type of bugs.

I think that it is a bit pointless to discuss the possible outcome of storing invalid geometries. Having that said, The consequences can include:

- Wrong results (that is, the `ST_Distance` will return inaccurate or plain wrong figures)
- Database performance issues: Keeping malformed data can seriously damage the database performance and create huge log file, because every function call will write an error to the log and disrupted the ordinary database work.
- Database crashes.
- Application crashes - either caused by receiving malformed data from the database, or by receiving unreasonable outcome (negative distance, for example).
- Phantom behaviour (see link above). This is the worst consequence of all. You'll have strange things happening. Slowdowns, data loss, crashes, unreasonable results, long pauses, no responsiveness and many other curses. You might not be able to spot them or reproduce them, because they all fall under the "undefined" category in every documentation.

My advice  - if small buffers do not significantly harm your data consistency, use them to prevent any of the above from happening. **Keep your data valid.**

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on using small buffers? How do I do that?

Comment: `ST_Buffer(the_geom, 0.0000001)` might do the trick for self intersection. Use it only if the consequences of a slightly larger geometry are not severe.

Comment: My experience is that correcting malformed data is quite an investigation. But even though it is time-consuming, it normally is worth the effort. The `ST_Buffer(the_geom, 0.0000001)` trick definitely helps a lot.

Comment: The thing is ST_Buffer fixes the geometry but the result is not really what I expected - for this invalid polygon here (http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/way/51954364) ST_Buffer only returns the top left rectangle.

ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology seems to be closer to what I need (valid geometry but as close as possible to the invalid original).

Any downsides in using ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology?

Comment: That geometry should be processed as a `MULTIPOLYGON` of two Polygons, not as a single `POLYGON`. Try to get the original WKT if possible.

Comment: `ST_MakeValid` can also be useful, but examine the results to ensure it succeeded and didn't produce a geometry collection.

Answer (score 16):

You can prevent invalid geometries entering your database in the first place. For PostgreSQL/PostGIS users, this is simple to do with [check constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS). For example, consider a table `public.my_valid_table` with a column of polygon geometries `geom`, use the following SQL/DDL:

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.my_valid_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_valid_geom CHECK (st_isvalid(geom));
```

Note: this table has to have valid polygons before enforcing the constraint.

If you then try to insert/add an invalid geometry, you will see an error:

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "my_valid_table" violates check constraint "enforce_valid_geom"
```