# how feasible is building my own map server? providing GeoCoding, Directions and Navigation

Tags: routing, server, direction, google-maps-api

My need is a **heavy** use of routing. same as Google's Directions API. I'm looking for a viable alternative to abusing google and paying them too much.

how difficult is it to have my own server for that task?

Comment: do you have a budget?

Comment: Are we talking routing for a county, state, country?

Comment: Mapperz, i have a small budget

Comment: CaptDragon, for a country.

Comment: Can I ask  1. Why do you want to do this?  2. How many users do you anticipate? 3. Can you elaborate on your Q to provide more info on what data your going to be using, the audience your targeting (and more info on the sort of load your expecting off this user-base), and the benefits you offer over sites such as Google, 4. How much budget, what existing IT-infrastructure do you have?  

With that info, id like to construct an Answer around using a service such as Amazon + Open Source to deal with these kind of requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly an answer, but have you seen [The Open Source Routing Machine (OSRM)](http://project-osrm.org/)

Their routing engine works on OSM-data it seems, but it is opensource, so it could provide som pointers. And their implementation is FAST: http://map.project-osrm.org/

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but performance isn't going to be anywhere near what you'd expect from google api on a small budget for an entire country. You should try it and report back :)

ArcGIS Server and Network Analyst is out of the question given the budget. So go with **Postgresql, PostGIS and pgRouting**.

[Route Maker did it for a few countries on 4GB RAM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20078/how-to-make-pgrouting-faster)