# Is there a way to use OSRM with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, routing, open-source-routing-machine

Is there a way to use OSRM with PostGIS (Windows)?

Related: [Why mobile routing is so fast?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83844/why-mobile-routing-is-so-fast)

Comment: Seem you can with http://luarocks.org/en/Download looking how MapBox implements this https://www.mapbox.com/blog/osrm-using-external-data/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear. I need to use OSRM from inside Postgre SQL queries, like I do by using pgRouting.

Comment: OSRM is a stack of tools that sits on top a database, but only the development branch support external data (postgis) https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/tree/develop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSRM does not use a database, but tuned data structure that are sometimes (falsely) called index. The process to go from raw OSM data to actual query processing is a multi-step process, i.e. extract, prepare, route. As Mapperz said, it is possible to query a SQL data base for additional data during the extraction process.

To query OSRM for routes from your SQL queries, you would need to connect via http to a running OSRM instance and parse the data.

Comment: So bad! it's not practical. My goal is to query OSRM for routes from SQL queries.