# What resources are there for PostGIS maintenance?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, maintenance

I am recommending the usage of a Postgres+PostGIS database to a client for storage of their Geospatial Data. I need to recommend the processes for maintenance of the database.

The Client is an Oracle user, so they are used to constant active maintenance of databases.

My personal experience of PostGIS has only been on small to medium databases, and they have been very low maintenance, requiring vacuuming once in a few months.

Where can I read about maintenance of Postgres+PostGIS databases?

Comment: Your question isn't exactly the same as [this one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/10260/4119), but the responses should be quite helpful.

Comment: @katahdin: You are quite right. That question has wonderful answers, and that's why I'm voting to close this as as duplicate of that one. I hadn't found that question when I  searched for Postgis and maintenance, so atleast this question might guide future google searches in that direction.