# How to improve poor performance times for PostGIS 2.1 Tiger Geocoder?

Tags: postgis, performance, tiger, geocoding

I've recently upgraded my PostGIS DB from 2.0 to 2.1.  I initially followed the instructions from [Waiting for PostGIS 2.1 - Install PostGIS Tiger Geocoder as an Extension](http://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/206-Waiting-for-PostGIS-2.1-Install-PostGIS-Tiger-Geocoder-as-an-Extension.html) and  [2.7. Installing, Upgrading Tiger Geocoder and loading data](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/postgis_installation.html#tiger_geocoder_loading_data) to load (for the first time) the 2012 Tiger Geocoder into the DB by grabbing the updated geocoder files from the postgis-pg92-binaries-2.1.1devw32.zip file.  Then I downloaded and installed the data for 5 western states. (OR, WA, ID, CA, MT).  Finally, I ran the `SELECT install_missing_indexes();` command after loading all of the data. I also ran `vacuum analyze` on the whole DB afterwards.  That all went fine, and the geocoding process is working.

However, while I am admittedly running this DB on a not-so-speedy laptop, my results of 2-8 sec results versus the 61ms results noted [here](http://postgis.net/docs/Geocode.html) seem a way out of whack.

**Any ideas on what I can do to improve performance?**

Guides I worked through to try to improve performance:

- [OpenGeo "Section 29: Tuning PostgreSQL for Spatial"](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/tuning.html)
- [OpenStreetMap "Tune the database "](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PostgreSQL)
- [Part 1: Getting Started With PostGIS: An almost Idiot's Guide (PostGIS 2.0)](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_tut01)
- [Best practices for PostGIS production environments?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10260/best-practices-for-postgis-production-environments)

and I've updated all of my postgresql.conf settings to match the highest settings from any of the documents.

**System specs**: Win 7 64 bit - Intel 2.3Ghz, 4GB RAM, Paging space 2000MB to 8000MB (fixed), PostgreSQL 9.2 (32 bit), Postgis 2.1

**Additional Details**:  When I run the following query using "explain analyze" I get the following results:

```
SELECT g.rating, ST_X(g.geomout) As lon, ST_Y(g.geomout) As lat, 
    (addy).address As stno, (addy).streetname As street, 
    (addy).streettypeabbrev As styp, (addy).location As city, (addy).stateabbrev As st,(addy).zip 
    FROM geocode('<house #> <street name>, <city> <state> <zip>') As g; 

Function Scan on geocode g  (cost=0.25..15.25 rows=1000 width=68) (actual time=185.606..185.606 rows=1 loops=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase your shared memory buffers in postgresql.

- http://www.westnet.com/~gsmith/content/postgresql/pg-5minute.htm
- http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2012/06/absurd-shared-memory-limits.html

Comment: Yeah, I already tried raising it from 32 to 500MB before posting, but I didn't really see an improvement.

Comment: the rhaas link has some other real good tips for postgres but I couldn't fine the specific post.

Comment: Try this performance tutorial. http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/394523-configuring-postgresql-for-pretty-good-performance

Comment: Well, I haven't got my 1st run results to be much better, but 2nd run results are in the 65ms range.  Thanks for all your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Your second run used 68ms because all needed data has been cached in RAM, which means your problem is not solved. Any new address will still need a new search.

Some ideas from my observation since I don't have more information of your setup:

1. Did you install the database in regular hard drive or SSD? I moved my database from SSD to regular hard drive and the speed dropped considerably.
2. If you are just testing, loading only 1 ~ 2 states data will have considerably better performance.
3. Put a comma between city and state.

Comment: Why is it required to put a comma? isn't Address normalization (which seems to be quite fast)  the first step of the geocoder script?

Comment: Whether it have a real impact depend on case, and I have no way to verify it. However I think there is no reason not to put a comma and reduce possible problems, especially for data with quality issues. The well formatted address may be easy to be normalized, but there are all kinds of errors you cannot predict in real world data.

Comment: Is there any method to measure the quality of an address before making the search?