# PostGIS geocoder size and performance

Tags: postgis, geocoding, performance

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.3.5 and PostGIS 2.1.2 on a 16Gb Ubuntu 14.04 system.

1. If I load all the states' TIGER data, using the scripts provided in Postgis, how big will the database be for the entire US?

   I have currently installed just the TIGER data for California (CA).
2. It takes about a minute to geocode an address.  I have read the performance hints suggested at [How to improve poor performance times for PostGIS 2.1 Tiger Geocoder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70398/how-to-improve-poor-performance-times-for-postgis-2-1-tiger-geocoder), and have tried setting the shared memory buffer to a much larger value.  I haven't been able to improve the query performance time.

Do you have suggestions?

Comment: Dan, did you ever get a clear answer to your question? I just hit 100GB loading the states alphabetically when I got to "wy" so it's probably around 100GB. I'm moving data around and rebuilding indexes now but can answer at least that part of the question in a little bit. My guess is that it's going to be 100-120GB.

Comment: Can you please share your server details like RAM size and other configurations?

Answer (score 2):

1. Total size for the data will be 105G. However you need some temp space for downloading and provisioning the database. I used to use a 120G SSD and it was filled up before finish. I assigned 180G to it in second time without problem. You probably need at least 105G + 30G, since my download folder after the job finish still have 30G files in it.
2. 1 min is not right and usually your problem is not in database config, since the default config should at least give you 300 ms. I'd suggest these directions:

   - Install the database in SSD. It make huge difference.
   - Format the address correctly, just like the `pprint` function output.

I cannot give more suggestions without more information of your setup and queries. You can check my blog post about [my setup](http://dracodoc.github.io/2015/11/17/Geocoding/) and [my script](http://dracodoc.github.io/2015/11/19/Script-workflow/).

Answer (score 0):

1. dracodoc has a good answer for you for this aspect of your question
2. 1 minute for a geocode query indicates that you haven't done step 15 of section 2.4.1 [here](https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#loading_extras_tiger_geocoder)