# How to make web mapping project run (serve map) faster?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver, loading

I'm implementing a project with openlayers 2.12, Geoserver 2.1.3 and PostgreSQL 9.1/PostGIS 2.0

I also use HTML5 Geolocation API and MapQuest's Geocoding API.

In the database I have data `(osm_line, osm_point, osm_polygon, osm_road)` of a county I downloaded from OpenStreet Map.

The user can also search for points. That's implemented with JavaScript and vector layers.

The problem is , after a certain zoom level (about 16/20) the tiles load **very** slow. Especially in FireFox and Internet Explorer.

Also, when panning, tiles are **blended** in Internet Explorer.

Please advice, how can I fix this?

Is there a way to make the whole system load faster?

**EDIT**

As for the IE problem, with tiles blending, a friend of mine Skyped me [this](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/929)

As for the loading speed issue, I checked the CPU usage and Geoserver goes up to 60-70, when postGis and browsers are about 08-10.

And I also remember that I edited the settings of Geoserver so I increased the SLD file limit.

Also the base layer is WMS, containing the four tables together
`{layers: 'cultumap:planet_osm_polygon, cultumap:planet_osm_line, cultumap:planet_osm_roads, cultumap:planet_osm_point'}`

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you provide more information about tile cache seeding in your environment? It sounds like your OSM data might be tile-cached up to zoom level 16 but after that point you're generating tiles on demand.

Comment: @tomfumb Hey.I just edited my question, added more info. About the cache seeding...How I check this? Sorry, no experience with that. Can you be more specific? Thanks

Comment: ideally you'd just ask whoever configured your GeoServer installation. Next best option might be exploring the GeoWebCache interface from the GeoServer administration page. If that's no use you might end up trawling the file system looking for your tiles. I think you should give some indication of what kind of performance you're getting, i.e. if tiles render after 2 - 3 seconds or it takes longer. Also read http://docs.geoserver.org/2.1.3/user/production/java.html on JAI and performance (though don't expect a massive change)

Comment: You first need to figure out what part of the application is slow. Is generating the tiles taking time? or is transfering the tiles over the network taking time?

Comment: @slevin doing a preview in geoserver might be helpful.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I have little experience with Geoserver. How do I check wich takes more time? And , what next? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here's my suggestions:

1. Try the map as just tiles. Is this slow? If so, use someone else's base map or use GeoWebCache to pre-generate tiles. Then all you should be seeing when loading only tiles is HDD usage and no or very little processing.
2. If you're loading vectors, and that's slow, don't load vectors. Tile the vectors and query the database for searching and return only the one vector you are active on.
3. You could try another web-mapping library. [Leaflet](http://Leafletjs.com) is a very simple and light-weight library that works well.

Comment: Since problems only occur at a certain zoomlevel switching to leaflet will not solve anything.

Comment: Well, where is the bottleneck? Can you run top on your server while you move aroudn on the map to see whether HDD/CPU/RAM are maxed out? Identify that bit, then find a solution to fix it.

Comment: @alexgleith Thanks for the anser. I have little experience with Geoserver, just the basics. So is there any tutorial on how to use GeoWebCache? Thanks

Comment: Check it out here: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/index.html

Basically, you use the http://server/geoserver/gwc/wms? endpoint rather than http://server/geoserver/wms? then you can generate a cache of all the tiles before hand to speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

To make the whole system load faster, you could:

- Cache the 'slow' zoom levels as raster tiles
- [Generalise/simplify](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440/) your vector data to adapt it to each 'slow' zoom level. Generalised data are faster to transfer and render on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [GeoServer on Steroids](http://elogeo.nottingham.ac.uk/xmlui/handle/url/226) for a detailed description of tuning GeoServer. But in this case the first thing to check could be how your PostGis DB is set up (see [Best practices for PostGIS production environments?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10260/best-practices-for-postgis-production-environments)).