# Improve render speed for QGIS canvas (hardware)

Tags: qgis, performance, hardware-recommendations

I'm using QGIS to build complex maps from OSM-Data (GPKG or PostGIS). I'm wondering, how I should upgrade my system, to speed up rendering in canvas:

Intel I5 4x3,2GHz, 16GB DDR3, SSD

Or what about using RAM-Disk or RAID?

In the GIF-Animation you can see real time rendering at changing scale: 
https://media.giphy.com/media/MUlt8lb1iuzm80alyE/giphy.gif
2 or more seconds for every canvas move or scale are just too much for a smooth work.

I already use parallel rendering for all CPU and simplification:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a bit off topic but, before investing in to hardware I suggest you first look into Postgres/PostGIS tunning.
Some starting points:

[Tuning PostGIS for production environments?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10260/tuning-postgis-for-production-environments)

[Performance Tuning PostgreSQL](https://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql-performance.html)

[Tuning Your PostgreSQL Server](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server)

[PostGIS preformance tips](https://postgis.net/docs/performance_tips.html)

[Tunning PostgreSQL on your Dedicated Server](https://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/dedicated/Tuning_PostgreSQL_on_your_Dedicated_Server)

From my experience you can greatly improve rendering preformance by increasing simplification treshold:

[image]

Its not clear data structure of your maps, I presume you have several layers for roads, contours, coverage etc... Reducing tables might help as well since "Overall storage is practically always (substantially) cheaper with a single table instead of multiple tables in 1:1 relationship." ([@Erwin Brandstetter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/99179)). You could achiev this by creating views for layers with same geometry.

If none of this helps enough start thinking of hardware.