# Cleaning geometries in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0

I am trying to do some processing on some very large polygon layers. However I am running into various geometry errors such as:

```
NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 470396.52017068537 141300.52235257279
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_intersection(geometry,raster,integer) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
SQL function "st_intersection" statement 1
NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 504154.61769969884 140782.04115761846
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_intersection(geometry,raster,integer) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
SQL function "st_intersection" statement 1
NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 505255.50242871145 140803.34860398644
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_intersection(geometry,raster,integer) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
SQL function "st_intersection" statement 1
NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 510312.46970004693 141215.29256710084
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_intersection(geometry,raster,integer) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
SQL function "st_intersection" statement 1
NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 510312.46970004693 141215.29256710084
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_intersection(geometry,raster,integer) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
SQL function "st_intersection" statement 1
NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 511839.50335641927 141115.85781738357
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_intersection(geometry,raster,integer) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
SQL function "st_intersection" statement 1
NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 515064.03024010791 140895.68087158105
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_intersection(geometry,raster,integer) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
SQL function "st_intersection" statement 1
NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 519233.18724611058 140881.47590733573
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_intersection(geometry,raster,integer) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
SQL function "st_intersection" statement 1
NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 521072.73011588014 141044.83299615697
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_intersection(geometry,raster,integer) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
SQL function "st_intersection" statement 1
NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 523331.31943088671 141144.26774587421
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_intersection(geometry,raster,integer) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
SQL function "st_intersection" statement 1
NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 523331.31943088671 141144.26774587424
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_intersection(geometry,raster,integer) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
SQL function "st_intersection" statement 1
NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 523395.24176999065 140725.22130063715
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_intersection(geometry,raster,integer) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
SQL function "st_intersection" statement 1
NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 524531.63890961662 140810.45108610913
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_intersection(geometry,raster,integer) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
SQL function "st_intersection" statement 1
```

I have tried the function suggested here: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiCleanPolygons

for cleaning geometries, the code I have used being:

```
UPDATE public.mytable
SET geom=cleangeometry(geom);
```

With the result:

```
ERROR:  GEOSisSimple: IllegalArgumentException: This method does not support GeometryCollection arguments
```

and also

```
UPDATE public.valid_mytable
SET geom=ST_MakeValid(geom);
```

This one works, but only if I first change my geometry column to geometry

```
ALTER TABLE public.mytable  ALTER COLUMN geom SET DATA TYPE geometry;
```

Which then leaves me with a table that no longer works with my other functions!

```
ERROR:  Relate Operation called with a LWGEOMCOLLECTION type.  This is unsupported.
```

I have tried changing the columns back to geometry(MultiPolygon)

ALTER TABLE public.my_table ALTER COLUMN geom SET DATA TYPE geometry(MultiPolygon);

But this fails

```
ERROR:  Geometry type (GeometryCollection) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
```

I have tried going through PostGIS in Action (Second Ed) http://www.manning.com/obe/ but I can only find functions for finding invalid geometries, but my data-set is so big to fix this manually, I really need something that will fix them automatically.

---

I have been able to isolate the problem polygons, when I try and run ST_MakeValid() I get the result:

```
ERROR:  Geometry type (GeometryCollection) does not match column type      (MultiPolygon)
 ********** Error **********

 ERROR: Geometry type (GeometryCollection) does not match column type      (MultiPolygon)
SQL state: 22023
```

I did a type check on my geometry column, and it said the type was "MULTIPOLYGON"

Comment: ST_MakeValid corrects as much as it can.

Comment: I see, thanks, I  had actually made a mistake in my question where I forgot to mention that it was ST_Make_Valid that causes the problems with my columns. I have used ST_MakeValid but I have to change my geom column to the geometry data type to get it to work, and once I do that I cant get it back to a geometry(MultiPolygon)

Comment: You can use the hack ST_Buffer(geom, 0) which will deal with many invalid geometries. You can also use ST_MakeValid. Finally, you could try selecting into a new table and putting ST_IsValid(geom) in the where clause.

Comment: Thanks, i tried the buffer hack already, but it didn't work, it wanted a geometry input rather than a geometry(MultiPolygon). I will try only selecting the valid polygons and see how many are filtered out.

Comment: I Have tried isolating the problem polygons, the type of my geometry column is listed as "MULTIPOLYGON" I have checked ST_MakeValid http://postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/ST_MakeValid.html and it says it takes multipolygons, however running it I get: ERROR:  Geometry type (GeometryCollection) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
********** Error **********

ERROR: Geometry type (GeometryCollection) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
SQL state: 22023

Comment: Ok. This comes from st_makevalid producing points and LineStrings along with polygons which will produce a GeometryCollection. There is a fix for this which I will write up in  couple of hours. I am about to go surfing :-)

Comment: Yeah, it was great, arms hurt :-) Answer posted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you only want Polygons or Multipolygons from [ST_MakeValid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeValid.html) you can use [ST_Dump](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) to extract the constituent geometries and then test for the geometry type. ST_MakeValid will sometimes produce Points or LineStrings which is where the GeometryCollection  is coming from. Try something like:

```
SELECT 
  g.geom, 
  row_number() over() AS gid,
FROM 
  (SELECT 
     (ST_DUMP(ST_MakeValid (geom))).geom FROM your_table
  ) AS g
WHERE ST_GeometryType(g.geom) = 'ST_MultiPolygon' 
   OR ST_GeometryType(g.geom) = 'ST_Polygon';
```

You could use an IN clause instead of OR condition, though the result and query plan would be the same. If you only want Multipolygons you can wrap [ST_Dump](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) in the [ST_Multi](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Multi.html) function.

The row_number() over() will simply return you a unique id, starting from one, for each geometry returned from ST_Dump. You can also use the path element returned by ST_Dump, with the same result.

You will presumably want to combine this with a CREATE TABLE cleaned_geoms AS SELECT .... type statement, as a direct update is unlikely to work as ST_MakeValid wil notl generally (or always) produce a one to one mapping from I put to output.

This is untested as I have no means, currently, so there might be a misplaced parenthesis, but the general principle is sound. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 22):

You can try [ST_CollectionExtract](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_CollectionExtract.html) to extract [Multi]Polygons from GeometryCollections. Use ST_Multi to force them as MuliPolygons.

```
UPDATE public.valid_lcmsouthshapefile
  SET geom=ST_Multi(ST_CollectionExtract(ST_MakeValid(geom), 3))
  WHERE NOT ST_IsValid(geom);
```

After your done, use a CHECK constraint to ensure they stay valid. See details [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11234/1872).